# Get Latency of a database connection

Tags: azure-sql-database, ping, sqlcmd, latency

I'd like to know a bash command to get the latency (response time) of a database connection.
I'm *not* interested in the performance of the database itself - I just want to know the latency to the database (server).
Or, to be more precise, I'm interested in the network latency between app server and PaaS database.

Actually, something like `ping` or `traceroute` would be fine. But I'm speaking of an Azure PaaS SQL. Sadly, this cannot get ping'd.

I had a look into `sqlcmd` but I could not find a suitable command which returns me the latency.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you interested in measuring the time it takes to login from some client A to the DBaaS? You could make a test app that measures the time [SqlConnection.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) took.

Comment: Actually I want to test the network latency on different App Server <-> database setups. One scenario is to compare (scenario 1) AppServer <-> IaaS DB with (scenario 2) AppServer <-> PaaS DB.

Comment: Yes, but how do you want to define network latency? The time it takes to establish a TDS connection with the server?

Comment: Yes, this would be fine. I just found `tcptraceroute`  but not sure if it's the right tool for me.